# ROS Answers SE migration: keras for ROS

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to deploy and use on ROS ( melodic or noetic) a simple deep learning network i developped with python ( on spyder environnement).

Do you have any example or any references to do this.

Evething I saw is about tensor flow and is very complex.

Thank's a lot.

Ben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375792/keras-for-ros/) by [bengao](https://answers.ros.org/users/73114/bengao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-09**:
Don't think about Keras, TensorFlow, OpenCV, point cloud, or any of this the most important thing you should think about is data and how you will send it to ros or your robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Ben,

> I want to deploy and use on ROS ( melodic or noetic) a simple deep learning network I developed with python ( on spyder environment).

There are few steps:

1. In your Keras model keep that file as a ROS node and then check the form of data and publish it.
2. After publishing, You can use that data as whatever you want.

Just for Example (Drone with hand signs): I have hand sign data based on the video stream(right, left, up, and down) and I have obtained a Keras model for it. Then I would suggest making the full model as a single node and then publish it. After publishing let's say I subscribed and I have a [string](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html)
and based on that particular string I can decide moments and give moments to the drone via tf and it performs the action.

In place of string, you can take any message like [Image](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html), [transformation](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Transform.html), coordinate, [pointcloud](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html) or even you can create your [custom message](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv).

Does this make sense? If you want in-depth understanding to write a comment. This is just an overview.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bengao](https://answers.ros.org/users/73114/bengao/) on 2021-04-09**:
Hi Karma!

I think I understand this. It's the first time I will use it.

I will try and If necessary, I will come back to complete my problem.

Thank's a lot !

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-12**:
Hello @bengao,

Do you think that you got your answer, then tick this as an answer to help others?

Yes! You can drop comments if you are having any trouble implementing this.  If you fill, this answer is good, please! vote up. Thanks!